# copy and pasting to the next empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I have this following code which copies BX2 to BX400 from "copySheet" and pastes it to first empty row in Column A of "pasteSheet".

```
 copySheet.Range("BX2:BX400").Copy
 pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial  xlPasteValues
```

Which code pastes it to first empty row in Column B then ?

Comment: change the `1` to a `2` in your `.Cells()` method. This is the column number, so 1 = A; 2 = B etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only concerned with pasting the values then direct value transfer is preferred as it does not involve the clipboard.

```
with copySheet.Range("BX2:BX400")
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value
end with
```

Comment: thanks. this does it when i only want to paste things to column B but if i want to copy another column for example Column C and try to paste it to Column D, changing B to D in your code does not work. It doesnt paste it to column D but another Column, like E or so. Do you know why this happens?